# Search for attachment sent to me in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, email

I know how to search for emails with attachments:

```
has:attachment
```

Which would return both emails from and to me with attachments.

However is there any way to search only attachments sent TO me? So it should exclude any emails with attachments that I send out.

Any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this query?

```
has:attachment to:me
```

#### Note :

- This means that the mails has attachment files AND they are the mails to owner.
- If you want to use email address, do it like this: `has:attachment to:emailAddress`

#### Reference :

- [Search operators you can use with Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en)